# How to prevent git from using the global config?

Tags: git

I have case where running some git related tests could generate failures if the user running them has some custom hooks installed inside his `~/.git-template/hooks` folder.

Mainly I do want to find a way to run `git` commands in insolation, where git would skip using the default hooks and maybe even loading other global configs.

Comment: `git config --local`

Comment: Looks like you can use the `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` and `GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL` env vars to ignore the system and global config files, respectively.  `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=true git <command>`  **EDIT**: Seems like `NOGLOBAL` is no longer supported, but `NOSYSTEM` should still work.

Comment: @0x5453 Make it an answer! It worked.

Answer (score 6):

To ignore the system config file (/etc/gitconfig), you can set the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` to `1`/`true`/`yes` before running your command.

e.g. `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=true git <command>`

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: This doesn't seem to disable `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: @HappyFace Correct, that environment variable only applies to the system-wide config file under `/etc`.  You could similarly suppress `~/.gitconfig` by overriding `$HOME`, though depending on the context that could have other unintended consequences.