# git: How do I prevent git from loading `~/.gitconfig`?

Tags: linux, bash, git, shell

How do I prevent git from loading `~/.gitconfig`?

I don't want to override `HOME`, as that might create other problems.

Related:

- [How to prevent git from using the global config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013504/how-to-prevent-git-from-using-the-global-config/45021500?noredirect=1#comment137856437_45021500)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the environment variable `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITCONFIGGLOBALcode) to tell `git` where to load the global configuration from.

If you tell it to load it from something like `/dev/null` it will basically not load anything.

```
$ GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=/dev/null git config --global --list
$
```

This shows that this way the global configuration will contain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A common workaround is to override your home folder only for the **git** command call duration, like follow:

```
HOME= git {git-arguments}
```

or

```
HOME=/dev/null git {git-arguments}
```

Comment: One potential reason could be that OP explicitly specified that they didn't want to change `HOME`.

Comment: OP wanted to avoid changing it permanently, yes, but isn't this a "just for this command" modification?

Comment: Yes, it is just for a single git invoke.

Comment: Setting `HOME` to the null string will cause `git` to look for `/.gitconfig`, resulting in a likely file-not-found error.

Comment: Setting `HOME` to `/dev/null` will *absolutely* cause an error when `git` tries to access `/dev/null/.gitconfig`,